# Python, name not defined

Tags: python

```
def main()

     name = input ("Please enter your name")

     print ("your name is", name)
```

In this program,(written in python `IDLE`) when I run it, and enter my name I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\********\Documents\PYTHON\hello world.py", line 66, in ?

   main()

  File "C:\Users\********\Documents\PYTHON\hello world.py", line 5, in main

    name = input ("Please enter your name")

  File "<string>", line 0, in ?

NameError: name 'Jim' is not defined
```

What does `not defined` mean? `Jim` was the input, how can I define the input while it could be any conbination of letters?

Comment: Try to write a script and execute it, it will be easier to understand.

Comment: For starters, you don't need parens around your print statement, but that was probably just a typo...

Answer (score 16):

`input()` in 2.x interprets its input as Python code. Use `raw_input()` instead. And stop applying 3.x documentation to 2.x.